# Where is passenger_config on Debian?

Tags: apache, debian, config, passenger

I'm running Debian 8,  I want to install Passenger for Apache and followed the instructions here -- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/jessie/.  However, when I get to the step about validating the config ...

```
myuser@myserver:/var/www/html/myuser.net/cindex $ sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
sudo: /usr/bin/passenger-config: command not found
```

I don't find this file anywhere on my system.  Where do I find the passenger-config or is the validation step outdated?

Comment: Can you run `which passenger{,-config}`?

Comment: Intiailly I got nothing, but then I installed passneger via "sudo passenger-config validate-install" and now I am able to run the command.

Comment: If this is working now, please write up what you did as an answer and mark it as accepted.